# Tkinter GUI freezing, used Thread then encountered RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

Please help

```py
def change_flag(top_frame, bottom_frame, button1, button2, button3, button4, controller):
    global counter, canvas, my_image, chosen, flag, directory
    canvas.delete('all')
    button5['state'] = DISABLED
    counter += 1

    chosen, options_text = function_options()
    right_answer_flag = get_right_answer_flag(chosen, options_text)
    #pdb.set_trace()

    try:
        location = directory + chosen + format_image
    except:
        controller.show_frame(PlayAgainExit)
        
    my_image = PhotoImage(file=location)
    canvas.create_image(160, 100, anchor=CENTER, image=my_image)

    button1["text"] = options_text[0]
    button2["text"] = options_text[1]
    button3["text"] = options_text[2]
    button4["text"] = options_text[3]

    button1['state'] = NORMAL
    button2['state'] = NORMAL
    button3['state'] = NORMAL
    button4['state'] = NORMAL

##############

        button5 = Button(
            next_frame,
            width=20,
            text="next",
            fg="black",
            #command=lambda: change_flag(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller))
            command=Thread(target=change_flag, args =(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller)).start)
            
        button5.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Hello,

I do not want the GUI to freeze, so I used threading for `button5` but then it is giving me the runtime error
of "You can start the threads only once" which is correct. But How should I resolve this problem?

Thanks for your help,
Abhay

Comment: Use `lambda` on the `command` option.

Comment: I saw your previous comment and added lambda too, it is not freezing but is not changing the next frame. Do you want me to post the entire code?

        button5 = Button(
            next_frame,
            width=20,
            text="next",
            fg="black",
            command=lambda: change_flag(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller))
            #command=lambda: Thread(target=change_flag, args =(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller)).start)

Answer (score 1):

```py
command=Thread(target=change_flag, args=(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller)).start
```

is to create an instance of the thread object and pass the reference of `start` function of the instance to the `command` option.  It is like below:

```py
# create an instance of the thread object
t = Thread(target=change_flag, args=(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller))
# pass the start function of the thread object to command option
button5 = Button(..., command=t.start)
```

So when the button is clicked, it starts the thread.  When the button is clicked again, the same thread instance is started again which is not allowed.

You can use `lambda`, so that when the button is clicked, a new instance of the thread object is created and started:

```py
button5 = Button(..., command=lambda: Thread(target=change_flag, args=(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller)).start())
```

Comment: yes, I got it, I said the same thing in my previous comment.
I did use lambda like this, GUI is not freezing but next is not changing the frame now
If you want I can paste the full code.



##############
 command=lambda: Thread(target=change_flag, args =(top_frame,bottom_frame,button1,button2,button3,button4,controller)).start)

Comment: @AbhaySingh You have missed the `()` after `start` when using `lambda`.

Comment: @acw1668 You might want to mention that `tkinter` can crash if used outside of the thread where the `tk.Tk` was created.

Comment: @TheLizzard I have the only solution mentioned by acw1668 at the moment, if you have a better solution, let me know.

Comment: @AbhaySingh This solution will be fine, but in rare cases it can crash `python` itself without a traceback. It will take quite a bit of time and effort to provide a better solution and I will need to know a lot about your code. Therefore, all I can say is that if you run into weird crashes without a traceback, separate the GUI code from the other threads.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you. If you want I can paste the full code, so I can make the program better, and if you can provide inputs I can quickly implement it in the current code.